# getting letter grade with structs in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner learning c++ and have what is probably an extremely easy problem to fix, but I am confused. I have a program to calculate grades based on quizzes and exams.

Whatever grade % I put, I get "F" as the letter grade. I can put 100% in for everything and will still get F as the letter grade.

**Here is the output I get:(I want the letter grade to be A for this)**

Quiz1: 10/10

Quiz2: 10/10

Midterm exam: 100/100

Final exam: 100/100

Final grade: 100

Letter grade: F

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct record
{
  double quiz1;
  double quiz2;
  double midterm, midterm_one;
  double final, final_one;
  double quiz_average;
  char final_grade;
  double total_grade;
};

void input(record& the_grades);
void output(record& the_grades);

    int main()
    {
    record grades;
    input(grades);
    output(grades);
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    
void input(record& the_grades)
{
    cout << "Enter quiz1 grade out of 10 :\n";
    cin >> the_grades.quiz1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter quiz2 grade out of 10 :\n";
    cin >> the_grades.quiz2;
    cout << "Enter midterm Exam grade out of 100 :\n";
    cin >> the_grades.midterm;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Final Exam grade out of 100 :\n";
    cin >> the_grades.final;
    cout << endl;
}

void output(record& the_grades)
{
the_grades.quiz_average = (((the_grades.quiz1/10) + (the_grades.quiz2/10))/2) * .25;
the_grades.final_one = (the_grades.final/100) * .5;
the_grades.midterm_one = (the_grades.midterm/100) *.25;
the_grades.total_grade = the_grades.quiz_average + the_grades.final_one + the_grades.midterm_one;

cout << endl << endl;
cout <<"Quiz1: "<< the_grades.quiz1 <<"/10";
cout << endl;
cout <<"Quiz2: "<< the_grades.quiz2 <<"/10";
cout << endl;
cout <<"Midterm exam: " << the_grades.midterm<<"/100";
cout << endl;
cout <<"Final exam: " << the_grades.final<<"/100";
cout << endl;
cout <<"Final grade: "<< the_grades.total_grade*100;
cout << endl;
cout <<"Letter grade: ";

    if(the_grades.total_grade < 60)
    {
    cout << "F";
    }
    if((the_grades.total_grade > 60)&&(the_grades.total_grade < 70))
    {
    cout << "D";
    }
    if((the_grades.total_grade > 70)&&(the_grades.total_grade < 80))
    {
    cout << "C";
    }
    if((the_grades.total_grade > 80)&&(the_grades.total_grade < 90))
    {
    cout << "B";
    }
    if(the_grades.total_grade > 90)
    {
    cout << "A";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    }
```

Comment: `the_grades.total_grade` is within the range from `0.0` to `1.0`, but is compared with `60`, `70`, `80`, and `90`. You also have to consider the cases where `the_grades.total_grade` is exactly `60`, `70`, `80`, or `90`, which are not handled by any of the `if` statements.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the actual output *as text* into your question. Then tell us how it differs from the expected output.

Comment: You can drop the over-specified (and incorrect) tests. Just create an if-ladder: `if (x < 60) { } else if (x < 70) { } else if (x < 80) { } else if (x < 90) { } else { }` This handles everything you want and covers the entire range if values you require.

Comment: You didn't spot that you print `the_grades.total_grade*100`, but compare to just `the_grades.total_grade` when grading.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [the answer from AIGUY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74684486/15261315), because this is C++, structs may contain member functions.  `letter_grade` is a pretty good candidate for this treatment.

```
struct record
{
  double quiz1;
  double quiz2;
  double midterm, midterm_one;
  double final, final_one;
  double quiz_average;
  char final_grade;
  double total_grade;

  std::string letter_grade() const {
    return total_grade >= 0.9 ? "A" :
           total_grade >= 0.8 ? "B" :
           total_grade >= 0.7 ? "C" :
           total_grade >= 0.6 ? "D" : "F";
  }
};
```

At which point you could just:

```
std::cout << the_grades.letter_grade();
```